# I need to know what would you call someone that "Believes everyone is the same" such as addicts/alcholics

Tags: single-word-requests, meaning, vocabulary, orthography, idiom-requests

I hate STIGMA , I am bipolar and a recovering addict. I get treated the same as someone who is still being destructive.
I AM SICK OF PEOPLE JUDGING ME AND NOT GIVING ME CHANCES because the term "Addict".

Someone please help me with a word for " Thinking everyone is the same"
 EX.- some people think black people of all the same
 Ex.- All Bipolar people are crazy

I hope this helps and I really hope someone out there can understand and know the answer!

Comment: Can you provide a sentence where you would use the word? It's not clear if you're looking for a noun, or an adjective, for example.

Comment: Anything Laurel , I actually wanted to paint with the words " I HATE YOUR STIGMA" so something along those lines , think out of the box if you have too!

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for "Stereotype" here - this from [Oxford online](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/stereotype):

> ### Stereotype
>
> NOUN
>
> 1 A widely held but fixed and oversimplified image or idea of a particular type of person or thing.
>
> ‘the stereotype of the woman as the carer’
>
> ‘sexual and racial stereotypes’
>
> 1.1 A person or thing that conforms to a widely held but oversimplified image of the class or type to which they belong.
>
> ‘don't treat anyone as a stereotype’

Seems to me to be exactly what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

**Tarred with the same brush.**

From [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/tarred-with-the-same-brush):

> If some people in a group behave badly and if people then wrongly think that all of the group is equally bad, you can say that the whole group is tarred with the same brush.

You can say "All addicts get tarred with the same brush, even the recovering ones". Or "Please don’t tar us all with the same brush". It’s a reasonably common idiom.